# How to filter a nested dictionary (pythonic way) for a specific value using map or filter instead of list comprehensions?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension, python-3.5

I've a nested dictionary.

```
>>> foo = {'m': {'a': 10}, 'n': {'a': 20}}
>>>
```

I'd like to filter specific values, based on the values of 'a'.

I can use list comprehensions for the purpose.

```
>>> [foo[n] for n in foo if foo[n]['a'] == 10]
[{'a': 10}]
>>>
```

Using list alone gives me the elements from foo (and not the values of the elements) - as expected:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: foo[x] if foo[x]['a']==10 else None,foo))
['m']
>>>
```

Using map returns me unwanted 'None' values:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: foo[x] if foo[x]['a']==10 else None,foo))
[{'a': 10}, None]
>>>
```

Combining these two, I can fetch the desired value. But I guess foo is iterated twice - once each for filter and map. The list comprehension solution needs me to iterate just once.

```
>>> list(map(lambda t: foo[t], filter(lambda x: foo[x] if foo[x]['a']==10 else None,foo)))
[{'a': 10}]
>>>
```

Here's another approach using just filter. This gives me the desired values but I'm not sure if iterating over values of a dictionary is a good/pythonic approach:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda x: x if x['a'] == 10 else None, foo.values()))
[{'a': 10}]
>>>
```

I'd like to know if:

1. What's the pythonic/recommended approach for this scenario?
2. If the last example using filter on dictionary values is an acceptable?

Regards

Sharad

Comment: Why do you want to use map/filter instead of list comprehensions?  List comprehensions are often more Pythonic.

Comment: What, precisely, is your desired result?  Is it `[{'a': 10}]`?  Is it `['m']`?  Or something else?

Comment: The pythonic way is to use list comprehensions, not map or filter.  Therefore your question, as it stands, cannot be answered.

Comment: @John: desired result [{'a': 10}]. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 7):

If you want to return the full nested dictionary if it contains `a`, a list comprehension is probably the cleanest way. Your initial list comprehension would work:

```
[foo[n] for n in foo if foo[n]['a'] == 10]
```

You can also avoid the lookup on `n` with:

```
[d for d in foo.values() if d['a'] == 10]
```

List comprehensions are generally considered more Pythonic than `map` or `filter` related approaches for simpler problems like this, though `map` and `filter` certainly have their place if you're using a pre-defined function.

> This gives me the desired values but I'm not sure if iterating over values of a dictionary is a good/pythonic approach.

If you want to return all values of a dictionary that meet a certain criteria, I'm not sure how you would be able to get around *not* iterating over the values of a dictionary.

For a filter-based approach, I would do it as:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x['a'] == 10, foo.values()))
```

There's no need for the `if-else` in your original code.

Comment: the example of filter based approach will return the list, not the dictionary.

Comment: Hi, what if we want to filter this dictionary and maintain the keys i.e. so the output would be {'m': {'a': 10}}..list(filter(lambda x: x['a'] == 10, foo.values())) returns [{'a': 10}] and i I change this to list(filter(lambda x: foo[x]['a'] == 10, foo)) then it returns ['m'].

Comment: Actually, I found the answer using a for loop ....new_foo = dict()
for(k,v) in foo.items():
    if v['a'] == 10:
        new_foo[k] = v ... Is there a more elegant way to do this using lambda expression?

Answer (score 6):

A list comprehension can do this beautifully.

```
>>> foo = {'m': {'a': 10}, 'n': {'a': 20}}
>>> [v for v in foo.values() if 10 in v.values()]
[{'a': 10}]
```

You don't need the for loop or the list comprehension if you are matching against a known key in the dictionary.

```
In [15]: if 10 in foo['m'].values():
    ...:     result = [foo['m']]
    ...:     

In [16]: result
Out[16]: [{'a': 10}]
```